Test case fails
When executing test case I'm getting this error:

Message: Moq.MockException:
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.Map(AnnotationMasterRequest)
Performed invocations:MockIMapper:1 (m):
No invocations performed.

Service method:
public async Task<ServiceResponse<AnnotationMasterResponse>> CreateAnnotation(AnnotationMasterRequest annotationMasterRequest)
{
    return await serviceResponseExceptionHandler.HandleAsync(async () =>
    {
        var annotationMaster = _mapper.Map<AnnotationMaster>(annotationMasterRequest);
        annotationMaster.AnnotationMasterId = Guid.NewGuid();

        var responseResult = await base.Insert(annotationMaster);
        return responseResult.DataResult;
    }, annotationMasterRequest);
}

Test case:
public class AnnotationMasterServiceTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IUnitOfWork> _unitOfWorkMock;
    private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapperMock;
    private readonly Mock<IServiceResponseExceptionHandler> _exceptionHandlerMock;
    private readonly AnnotationMasterService _service;

    public AnnotationMasterServiceTests()
    {
        _unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
        _exceptionHandlerMock = new Mock<IServiceResponseExceptionHandler>();
        _service = new AnnotationMasterService(
            _unitOfWorkMock.Object,
            _mapperMock.Object,
            _exceptionHandlerMock.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task CreateAnnotation_ShouldReturnSuccess_WhenValidRequest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new AnnotationMasterRequest 
        {
            AnnotationMasterName = "test"
        };
        var annotationMaster = new AnnotationMaster();

        var annotationMasterResponse = new AnnotationMasterResponse { /* populate fields */ };

        // Create a mock ServiceResponse that returns a valid response, but we don't need to access internal properties.
        var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<AnnotationMasterResponse>
        {
            // Leave the internal properties (DataResult, Success, Message) as they are
            // Your test doesn't need to access them directly; we assume the ServiceResponse is set up correctly
        };

        _mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<AnnotationMaster>(request)).Returns(annotationMaster);

        _exceptionHandlerMock.Setup(e => e.HandleAsync(It.IsAny<Func<Task<AnnotationMasterResponse>>>(), request)).ReturnsAsync(serviceResponse);

        // Act
        var result = await _service.CreateAnnotation(request);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.Equal(serviceResponse.DataResult, result.DataResult);
        _mapperMock.Verify(m => m.Map<AnnotationMaster>(request), Times.Once);
    }

Mapper:
public class AnnotationMasterMapper : Profile
{
    public AnnotationMasterMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<AnnotationMasterRequest, AnnotationMaster>();
        CreateMap<AnnotationMaster, AnnotationMasterResponse>();

        CreateMap<Annotation, AnnotationResponse>();
    }
}

I tried this code, and I am expecting the test case to run successfully.

serviceResponseExceptionHandler.HandleAsync isn't actually doing anything so won't call your inner mock object

what is the work around in test case to get this worked

Don't call _mapperMock.Verify or don't mock the serviceResponseExceptionHandler object?

Your code is obviously xunit. Please don't tag the question nunit, causing folks who answer nunit questions to waste time. To get people with mocking expertise to view your question, tag it with the particular mocking framework you use.

@YashDepani you would need to capture the function as an argument and invoke it so that its expression body is executed.

The function needs to be captured as an argument and invoked so that its expression body is executed.
...

_exceptionHandlerMock
    .Setup(e => e.HandleAsync(It.IsAny<Func<Task<AnnotationMasterResponse>>>(), It.IsAny<AnnotationMasterRequest>()))
    .Callback((Func<Task<AnnotationMasterResponse>> func, AnnotationMasterRequest req) => {
        func(); //<-- invoke the function
    })
    .ReturnsAsync(serviceResponse);

...

assuming that the test arranged the necessary members to allow the invoked function to be executed to completion.
